# Benchmarking Node.JS server

Tags: node.js, redis, socket.io, benchmarking

I've written a Node.JS server which I would like to benchmark. It has the following components that I would like to benchmark separately:
- socket.io: how many continuous connections can it accept and process (where is the saturation point)
- redis: the same as above
- express: don't want to benchmark it

I know there is quite some (not a lot) documentation about that on the internet, but I don't like to reinvent the wheel, plus I don't want to actually spend countless hours of time trying some solution that turns out to be wrong for the job.

This is why I'm asking you guys here: what should I use to get a number/graph (whatever) on the number of simultaneous connections that server can process simultaneuosly without being bogged down? It would also be nice to monitor cpu, memory and swap of the process (yeah, yeah I know I can use countless of techniques or write my own script, but maybe something like that exists already).

I'm not looking for an answer where you'll paste a link to some solution that I already know it exists, I would like an answer in such a way, so that the person giving it has some actual experience and can really make a point or two and point me in the right direction.

Thank you

Comment: For Redis, you might want to have a look at: http://redis.io/topics/benchmarks

Answer (score 0):

You can use ApacheBench `ab` to test the load that your server may take - [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ab)

Some nice tutorials :

- [nixcraft/howto-performance-benchmarks-a-web-server](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-performance-benchmarks-a-web-server.html)
- [petefreitag/Using Apache Bench for Simple Load Testing](http://www.petefreitag.com/item/689.cfm)

Usage :

`$ ab -k -n 1000 -c 100 www.yourserver.com`

`-k` - keep alive

`-n N` - will send `N` requests to the server

`-c X` - will send `X` packets concurrently